# Why am i getting execute binary file error?

Tags: linux, centos, bash-scripting, centos-6

i am getting following email every 10 min. as I own the VPS. I am not expert in linux and am learning to manage linux servers. Please help me why am i getting these emails and how to stop them or how to fix the issue i am running CentOS 6 on 123-reg VPS

> Subject: Cron /usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1 /usr/lib64/sa/sa1: line 11:
>   /bin/date: cannot execute binary file /usr/lib64/sa/sa1: line 13:
>   /bin/date: cannot execute binary file

and below email every 1 hour Subject: Cron run-parts /etc/cron.hourly /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron: line 6: /bin/date: cannot execute binary file
/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron: line 6: [: =: unary operator expected
```

in 0anacron its:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Skip excecution unless the date has changed from the previous run 
if test -r /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily; then
    day=`cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily`
fi
if [ `date +%Y%m%d` = "$day" ]; then
    exit 0;
fi

# Skip excecution unless AC powered
if test -x /usr/bin/on_ac_power; then
    /usr/bin/on_ac_power &> /dev/null
    if test $? -eq 1; then
    exit 0
    fi
fi
/usr/sbin/anacron -s
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the cotents of your `0anacron` file

Comment: Sorry for that i have just added it , thanks David

Comment: Did you check: `/bin/date` and `ls -l /bin/date` ?

Comment: it gives me -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 41365188 Mar 17 16:29 /bin/date if i do ls -l /bin/date

Comment: As the same user as the CRON job, at a command line, please post the out of 'which date' and 'file `which date`' preserve the back-tick quotations.  The cron job is probably running as root - check this with 'crontab -l' as root and you should see the appropriate commands listed.

Comment: What happens if you just run `date` (or `/bin/date`) from your shell prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `0anacron` error:

---

This is the correct code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Skip excecution unless the date has changed from the previous run 
if test -r /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily; then
    day="$(cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily)"
fi
if [ "$(date +%Y%m%d)" == "$day" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

# Skip excecution unless AC powered
if test -x /usr/bin/on_ac_power; then
    /usr/bin/on_ac_power &> /dev/null
    if test $? -eq 1; then
        exit 0
    fi
fi
/usr/sbin/anacron -s
```

This fixes the `[: =: unary operator expected` problem. Here you're a list of fails corrected on the code sorted by relevance, the first is the worst:

- **In bash conditional you missed a equal sign. Is `==` instead of `=`**.
- `` ` `` (backtick) Is deprecated, use `$(command)` instead of `` `command` ``
- You ended the 8th line with a semicolon when there isn't need to do that.
- Indent your code 2 or 4 spaces uniformly.

#### `date` error:

---

Your `/bin/date` binary seems to be corrupted, did you see that [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/676410/why-am-i-getting-execute-binary-file-error)?